# background download in queue windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, download, windows-phone-8.1, queue, background-application

I am using `DownloadOperation` Class to enable background file download in my windows phone 8.1 app.

I used this method for download start:

```
await download.StartAsync().AsTask(_cts.Token, progressCallback);
```

where download is of `DownloadOperation` type.

Here I want to download single file at a time. If I call above method in loop then multiple files are started downloading at a time although they can continue download in background can lead to memory consumption.

But, If I used `await` and wait till download complete then I can download single file at a time.

**My issue in single download is**: If app goes in background then only current file is downloaded in background and others are after resume.

So how can we achieve background **single file download** in *queue* efficiently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the first option is the correct way, there should be no memory corruption

Comment: but I want to download single file at a time like in queue.